# Right way to use moshi in Java+kotlin project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, moshi

Currently, My android project has parts of codebase both in Java & Kotlin.

We are using Moshi with retrofit.

Time and again I keep getting weird problems in interoperability between java & kotlin that Moshi couldn't get through.

I believe I am missing something.

I suspect there are some dependency problems in versions of moshi & moshi-kotlin, which maybe I am not using right.

Following are the dependencies I am having currently.

`implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.8"
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter:moshi:2.6.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0"`

I create retrofit service in the following manner.

```
KotlinJsonAdapterFactory adapterFactory = new KotlinJsonAdapterFactory();
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(adapterFactory).build();
MoshiConverterFactory moshiKotlin = MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi);

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(new GranularErrorsCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(moshiKotlin)
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()
            .create(RetroFitService.class);
```

My Doubts are:

1. Do I need to add both Moshi & Moshi-kotlin?
2. Do I need to add 2 converter factory `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` & default provided by `MoshiConverterFactory.create()`
3. Anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You confusing with `kotlin` and `android`, Let me clear `kotlin` support android so you not need to add both converter factory. For more read [Advanced JSON parsing techniques using Moshi and Kotlin](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/advanced-json-parsing-techniques-using-moshi-and-kotlin-daf56a7b963d) article.